# Parser Error: Server Error in '/' Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, code-behind

I got the following error: "An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request.  Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately."

```
Parser Error Message: `Could not load type 'nadeem.MvcApplication'`.
Source Error:  Line 1:  <%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="nadeem.MvcApplication" Language="C#" %>
```

Comment: Be sure that your DLLs of your project are in the proper path. You may set the *output path* of you build in another folder outside your project, and when, for example, the project runs and searches for DLLs in the `bin` folder, it doesn't find them.

Comment: If that's because you change the default output directory, you can use this way:http://stackoverflow.com/a/26237022/1900498

Comment: y'all aren't going to believe this but this project in our solution wasn't selected in the Solution Configuration Manager to be built so there *was* no DLL being created in /bin !    Just make sure your project in question is selected to build in the Configuration Manager....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me Deleting the dlls from the BIN folder and then building the project worked

Answer (score 57):

Right-click your `Global.asax` file and click `View Markup`.  You will see the attribute `Inherits="nadeem.MvcApplication"`.  This means that your `Global.asax` file is trying to inherit from the type `nadeem.MvcApplication`.

Now double click your `Global.asax` file and see what the class name specified in your `Global.asax.cs` file is.  It should look something like this:

```
namespace nadeem
{
    public class MvcApplication: System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
    ....
```

If it doesn't, then you will receive the error you received.  The value in the `Inherits` attribute of your `Global.asax` file must match a type that is derived from `System.Web.HttpApplication`.

Comment: I am facing same problem as mentioned above.Whatever answers elaborate you all things are same as discussed you but still my error same

Answer (score 40):

I had this exact same issue when I downloaded the project source into two locations. The issue turned out to be by downloading the source it altered the sites virtual directory location and since I had not rebuilt the second source there were no DLLs there.

1. To fix this issue open the project you wish to build and go to the
   web sites properties (Project menu)
2. Create the virtual directory for
   the project.
3. rebuild the project.

Fixed

Comment: Where is this "web site properties"? I can't find it, can you please add a screenshot?

Comment: This saved me. I moved the project folder to a different location on disk and this step fixed it!

Answer (score 9):

After going through all of my projects in my Solution to set the compile to output to **bin\debug** and **bin\release**, this problem started for me. I finally realized that the startup project (i.e. the project with global.asax) needed to output to **bin** only.

Answer (score 8):

Since normally you create an MVC project the Global.asax markup has something like the following:

```
<%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="StackOverflow.MvcApplication" Language="C#" %>
```

Have you placed the Global.asax.cs in another project? If you have remove the CodeBehind="..." declaration from Global.asax and change the Inherits="..." declaration to reference the correct namespace and classname as it is defined in Global.asax.cs file.

If you haven't moved it try a Clean and then Rebuild of the Project in Visual Studio using the context Menu on the Web project. That worked for me when I got this error.

Comment: None of this works for me, I am unable to compile my app with the Global.asax folder there. Is it possible to delete it and re-add the file?

Answer (score 7):

1. Go to Project Properties
2. Look Output Path in the Page bottom
3. Change path to:   bin\
4. Save and Run Project

Answer (score 6):

The case is solved, but you may also get this error if your project is building to a different directory than IIS_Virtual_Directory\bin and dlls are missing.

Comment: This was the case for me

Answer (score 4):

As Kevin answered. I was changing the project name and namespacing in my MVC project. When I ran the application I got the same error "Line 1: <% .....".

To fix this, I needed to update the namespace within `Global.asax` (`Right Click` -> `View Markup`) then in the `Inherits` attribute update this to "`<correct root namespace for MVC project>.MvcApplication`".

Answer (score 0):

simply just copy the  project to another location and run  it will work i think problem because of the cleaning is not correctly done and there may be setup change  in the output /bin

Answer (score 0):

When I got this error it was after I deleted and recloned a Git folder; what happened was I forgot to build the solution in VS2010.  As soon as I built it, everything worked fine.  Sometimes it's something really simple like that.

Comment: Yep, I started getting this error for no good reason, cleaned and rebuilt the solution, and the error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

In my situation I was getting this same error. I am using git along with Source Tree for version control. In my case git had been enabled in the project, but I wasn't using Visual Studio to stage my commits, etc .. I was using Source Tree. This doesn't really matter what I was using the problem is that visual studio had put the following line into my **gitignore** file:

```
#Build Results
[Bb]in/
```

That was ignoring the bin folder so my bin folder never got pushed up to the server, once I removed that line and committed the entire bin directory and pushed it up to the server and then went to the server and did a git pull. The bin folder showed up and everything started working!

BTW, my final gitignore file (#Build results) section ended up looking like this:

```
# Build results

[Dd]ebug/
[Rr]elease/
x64/
build/
[Oo]bj/
```

Im still unsure if I need the Obj folder to be pushed to the server, but everything is working fine now.

Comment: The bin folder should be created and populated by building your projects. Unless you have copied some files there manually, there is no reason to store it in any version control repository.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the solution was the next:

1. Verify the markup of Global.asax, in the attribute **Inherits** I had this Inherits="NameOfMyProject.Global"
2. Then, verify the Global.asax.cs and I found this:

   public class Global_asax : System.Web.HttpApplication
3. Therefore, I changed the attribute **Inherits** in my Global.asax, and finally the markup was the next:

   Inherits="NameOfMyProject.Global_asax"
4. Also, I started the: ASP.NET state service, in the Administrative Tools. Then, my app run normally.

Answer (score 0):

I was learning from a video resource and ran into this error when told to hit Ctrl-F5 in the View in order to load it directly. By doing this, I ran into the same error message you posted.

In order to fix this, I built the solution (Build > Build Solution or Ctrl+Shift+B) and then retried.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it helps:
if you use a folder other than the default project ( naprmer on the D drive , in the case of Windows), then change to the default folder , create the project , run it. Then again, you can create projects in the folder in which you want . Strange. But this has helped in my case.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when i was trying to merge two solutions.
the problem was the namespace was not well configured in all files.
one part of story solved with @Kevin Aenmey answer but many other's ... not!

so the only way for me was to search for old namespace in the whole solution and replace them all with new namespace.maybe not the best option but in case of bad luck works nice

Answer (score 0):

This error causes when Namespace is Renamed.

-

> 1. Go to Folder Explore **( Don't Use Solution Explore)** . Find **Global.asax** File

.

[image]

> 2. Open File (in Notepad / any editor) and Change Replace **Old namespace** name **New Namespace**

.
[image]

> 3. **Save** It should work now..

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and that was because I didn't build the solution. Rookie mistake. Just: build solution (Ctrl + shift + b)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem after adding a new project to my solution. The solution built, no problem - but then bombed at runtime.

It turned out that the new project was set to target .NET 4.6.1 by default, whereas everything else in mhy solution targets .NET 4.5.

Changing the target framework in the new project to .NET 4.5 to match the others fixed the problem.

(thanks for no warning on that one Microsoft guys)

Answer (score 0):

I use `FTP` to upload `DLL`s of my site on the server but sometimes this error happen when the main `DLL` of the website has not been uploaded correctly on the server.

So I recommend you to **rebuild** you project and **re-upload main `DLL`s** on the server again.

Answer (score 0):

In our case - deleting all the contents of a published intranet site, and republishing the project that worked fine in debug fixed the problem.