# Changing output directory in MVC Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am having a problem with my MVC application after I set a different output folder instead of the default Bin folder . I also deleted the bin folder .

This resulted in Global.asax file exception  "Cannot load the type Global.Mvc application" during application runtime.

I am trying to get rid of all the bin folders to have just one output folder for my application . I would like to know if it is possible at all to get rid of the bin folder completely . Am I missing some setting here or is it a must to have bin folder  ?

Comment: So did you find the problem?

Comment: No, I had to stick to the default bin folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find a way to change bin folder.
Just like you say, When we change the default output folder:"bin\", then it will display some exception, Maybe that's a bug from visual studio.

Actually a lot people want to change the default bin folder to some RAM disk position, then it will save HDD life(don't let the HDD always write again and again), also very fast for read and write.

We can't change the default address, but we can change it use this way(delete bin folder before):

Open CMD.exe(administrator mode), put this code and execute:

```
mklink /d "Your project folder\bin" "new address(like RAM disk address)\bin"
```

mlink can redirect the original folder position to new position. Then, all fine such like you need.