# IIs Error: Application Codebehind=“Global.asax.cs” Inherits=“nadeem.MvcApplication”

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to deploy my web project and I keep getting this error:

```
Line 1: <%@ Application Codebehind=“Global.asax.cs” Inherits=“nadeem.MvcApplication” Language=“C#” %>
```

I looked at this post: [Parser Error: Server Error in '/' Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11596352/line-1-application-codebehind-global-asax-cs-inherits-nadeem-mvcapplicat)

But it is currect in my project.

I suspect it something with my iis7 configuration.

Any ideas?

Global.asax:

```
<%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="tamal.pelecard.biz.MvcApplication" Language="C#" %>
```

Global.asax.cs:

```
namespace TamalTest
{
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

public class MvcApplication : HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }

    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    }

    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Anything more explicit in event viewer ?

Comment: Can you show your Global.asax.cs code

Comment: is it exact code of file??

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Solved, just renamed the **Global.asax** or delete it fixed the problem :/

Other known related bugs I found on  the web:

1. **Global.asax.cs**: must inherit from `HttpApplication -> public class MvcApplication : HttpApplication`
2. Project output must be the bin folder and not **Bin/Debug**, etc.
3. Iss application pool is not in the correct .net version.

Comment: As for me have different class name in Global.asax.cs and in Global.asax markup. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11596396/3878876) help me.

Comment: What ? why i shouldn't be using bin/debug ?

Comment: For me I've deleted the Global.asax file and then restore from recycle bin, and the delete the bin folder and obj. Rebuild solution.

Answer (score 10):

You can change it by editing Global.asax file (not Global.asax.cs). Find it in app folder in windows explorer then edit

`<%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="YourAppName.Global" Language="C#" %>`

to

`<%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax" Inherits="YourAppName.MvcApplication" Language="C#" %>`

Comment: My issue was the namespace in the global.asax.cs file was "main_site", but the global.asax file (edited in text editor) needed to be "main_site.Global"

Answer (score 6):

It may occur due to the clean solution.The dlls in the bin will be removed.
1.Clean Solution
2.Rebuild the solution
3.If the build process have failed,not all the necessary dlls will be stored in the bin.
This is another scenario where the error occurs

Comment: This is closer to why I think the answer is correct. I just published and looks like the debug files I had been using previously had been cleaned for the release compile and publish. Error was fixed once I recompiled as debug mode, as that is where my local website was running from.

Answer (score 2):

Problem could occur if you have changed the namespace of your project.

Change the Namespace from Project Properties and also replace all old Namespace with new ones. **Renaming to correct namespace** might fix the issue.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2005949/1161370)

Answer (score 2):

It's quite weird. Every time I face this issue, have different solution. This time all of the previous fixes failed then I changed project output path from Bin to ..\Build\Bin. It failed. Reverted output path to the previous value , i.e., Bin fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Same issue i faced , when copy the project from another system. In my case i fixed this issue:

**delete everythings from inside Bin folder.**
**Clean & Rebuild the app again**

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing above worked for me. Everything was correct.

Close the Visual Studio and reopen again. This fixed the issue in my case.

The problem could have been caused by different versions of visual studio. I have Visual studio 2017 and 2019. I had opened the project on both the versions simultaneously. This might have created different set of vs files.

Close any instance of the Visual Studio and open again.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. It is solved by following steps

Go to IIS -> find your site -> right click on the site -> Manage Website -> Advanced Setting -> Check your physical path is correct or not.

If it is wrong, locate the correct path. This will solve issue.

Answer (score 1):

The only solution that worked for me

1. Run, Type command %Temp% -> Deleting "Temporary ASP.NET Files".

Other solutions I have tried, which didn't work.

1. Cleaning/Rebuilding
2. Cleaning bin, obj folders
3. Changing namespace

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting this error, I deleted dlls from my debug folder and when I started a new instance for debug I got this error. For me the issue was due to the the build setting, Release was selected in the build type, I just changed it to debug and then application was working fine

Answer (score 0):

In my case problem occurred after namespace renaming. I didn't use external tool like Re-sharper, I did renaming manually.

In that process, Views/Web.config file was left unchanged. After replacing old namespace name with the new one in this file, the error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

In my case my site on IIS was pointing to a different project than the one I was running on visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error on IIS Express. In my case, I had two projects as startup projects.I changed properties of the solution to single startup project and ran it. then changed it to previous settings and ran the solution again and no error occurred again!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the ***Inherits*** is pointing to the right namespace of the class because when you create an MVC project under a solution the ***Inherits*** value will miss the project name. Therefore you need to fill the gap(project name) manually.

```
<br><br><%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="solutionName.projectName.MvcApplication" Language="C#" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar error, tried all the suggestions above, but did not resolve. what worked for me is this:

Right-click your `Global.asax` file and click `View Markup`. You will see the attribute `Inherits="nadeem.MvcApplication"`. This means that your `Global.asax` file is trying to inherit from the type `nadeem.MvcApplication`.

Now double click your `Global.asax` file and see what the class name specified in your `Global.asax.cs` file is. It should look something like this:

```
namespace nadeem
{

public class MvcApplication: System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
    ....
```

But if it doesn't look like above, you will receive that error, The value in the Inherits attribute of your `Global.asax` file must match a type that is derived from `System.Web.HttpApplication`.

Check below link for more info:

[Parser Error: Server Error in '/' Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11596352/parser-error-server-error-in-application/44476086)

Answer (score 0):

Deleting `Global.asax` and restarting Visual Studio fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  It would be nice to mention what exactly this does, in particular if it has any potential side effects.

Answer (score 0):

I'd a similar problem in WebAPI (related MVC).

I fixed with:

Adding ".Global" to inherits in .asax file (not asax.cs)

```
Inherits="mynamespace.WebAPI.Global"
```

and changing the public class (asax.cs)

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
```

Answer (score 0):

In My case the issue was fixed by changing the solution platform from AnyCPU to x86.

Answer (score 0):

I found that this problem happened to me and to a colleague after changing the name of our solution/project.

The issue resulting from my colleague: I pulled changes into my branch and had the error. In my bin folder I found the old .dll files sitting with the newly named .dll files. Deleted the old ones and the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was also caused by old dlls. Clean all your files then rebuild.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Since this answer was already provided, please update the corresponding one, rather than adding a new answer that does not bring any information over it

Comment: VS2019.. This didn't work for me, it just complained it couldn't find the file when I restarted VS. Are you missing steps in your solution?

Answer (score 0):

[Right Click > Open Folder in File Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEpkZ.png)

If you are in the directory, find **Global.asax** not the **Global.asax.cs**

[Right click on **Global.asax** file then find Open with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjYMp.png)

[Change Inherits="ProjectNameThatHasError.MvcApplication" to Inherits="YourNamespaceNow.MvcApplication"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvljY.png)

You can open it in Notepad, Visual Studio any version, anyways you'll be editing text.

Answer (score 0):

Check your imported References the Target framework version. In my case, I add a reference that was not the same Target framework.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, Unload and reload project. Make sure The Global.asax is included in the project

Answer (score 0):

for the above error i deleted the global.asax file then restarted visual studio.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In my case my folder was named "Application%20example" rather than "Application example", is a bug when using Azure DevOps, you simply have to rename the folder. Also if you have empty folders in azure DevOps it won't upload them.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I copied the project and pasted it as another project. The `Global.asax` file contains the wrong file name, so I just change

```
<%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" 
    Inherits="WrongAppname.MvcApplication" Language="C#" %>
```

to

```
<%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" 
    Inherits="RightAppName.MvcApplication" Language="C#" %>
```