# Parse Error in Global.asax after Publishing to Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have deployed my ASP.Net MVC 5 application to Azure Web Apps.  All has worked well until I added Application Insights yesterday.  Since then, each attempt to publish my [site](http://mfeweb.azurewebsites.net) results in a parse error.  I've reviewed the application logs and telemetry but cannot discern how things have gone awry.  Are there specific changes that need to be made to `global.asax` in order for Application Insights to place well?

Update:
I found that the web project properties Assembly Name had been accidentally modified (rookie move).  I have changed it, cleaned, rebuilt, published all to no avail.  Output of parse error is:

```
Parser Error Message: The type 'MobileFirst452.MvcApplication' is ambiguous:   
it could come from assembly 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\bin\licationSeri.DLL' or 
from assembly 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\bin\MobileFirst452.DLL'. Please specify 
the assembly explicitly in the type name.
```

I deleted contents from bin folder.  The contents of `global.asax` are as follows:

```
<%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" 
Inherits="MobileFirst452.MvcApplication" Language="C#" %>
```

Comment: Please give more specifics on the parse error you are getting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parser Error: Server Error in '/' Application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11596352/parser-error-server-error-in-application)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After posting the above update, I reviewed the files deployed to Azure.  I deleted the DLL that was causing the error and can now finish testing the site.  Word to the wise:  check project properties prior to publishing just in case something was accidentally over-typed.