# Server error when publishing to local IIS - Global.asax

Tags: c#, iis, global-asax, http-status-code-500

I am trying to publish class library to local IIS.
When trying to enter the URL, I'm getting this error and this is driving me crazy!
I have no idea what causing this[image]

Comment: We can't help much without seeing that's in Global.asax

Comment: This is due to an error in the global.asax file. You need check it. Right-click your Global.asax file and click View Markup. For more information about it, you can refer to this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11596352/parser-error-server-error-in-application/44476086